# Converting an ISeq to IPersistentList

Tags: clojure

The problem is quickly stated: Given any seq (esp. `LazySeq`), create an instance of `clojure.lang.IPersistentList` maintaining order of elements.

I have a solution and it might be obvious why I don't like it:

```
(defn ->list
  [sq]
  (into '() (into '() sq)))
```

The problem with lists is that `(into '() ...)` will reverse the order of elements, so I have to do it twice:

```
(into '() [1 2 3])
;; => (3 2 1)
```

Other attempts that are less verbose and more "efficient" seem to not be able to produce a `clojure.lang.IPersistentList`:

```
(defn try-it
  [f]
  (let [r (f (range 10))]
    (assert (= r (range 10)))
    (class r)))

(try-it #(into '() %))   ;; => #<AssertionError ...>
(try-it seq)             ;; => clojure.lang.ChunkedCons
(try-it doall)           ;; => clojure.lang.LazySeq
(try-it #(concat '() %)) ;; => clojure.lang.LazySeq
(try-it #(concat % '())) ;; => clojure.lang.LazySeq
(try-it
  (comp 
    doall
    #(concat % '())))    ;; => clojure.lang.LazySeq
```

**TL;DR:** There is `vec` to convert seqs to vectors, `set` to create sets from them - what would be an appropriate equivalent for Clojure lists?

Comment: Convert a sequence: to a *set* if you want to test for membership quickly; to a *vector* if you want fast access to elements by position or to append elements. But **why convert a sequence to a list**?

Comment: I basically have two conversion functions `f`/`g` that are supposed to guarantee `v == (g (f v))` with `(class v) == (class (g (f v)))`. That's all there is to it - no semantic problem, just a contract to fulfill.

Comment: This is fragile, I think. Are you sure that `(= (class ()) (class (rest (cons :a ()))))`? Are you sure it will always be so? Corresponding manipulations with maps could well trip you up: `(= (class {}) (class (apply  dissoc (into {} (map-indexed vector (range 10))) (range 10))))` is `false`.

Comment: Context is __[this](https://github.com/xsc/rewrite-clj/blob/ys/rewrite/test/rewrite_clj/node/coerce_test.clj)__: I convert an s-expression to a custom tree-like structure (to be used in a zipper implementation) that can be manipulated and then converted back to an s-expression. While obviously not a necessity, it surely would be neat to have classes preserved in that roundtrip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, crap, if I had used the time to write the question to think - I might not have been in need for an answer in the first place.

```
(apply list (range 3))   ;; => (0 1 2)
(try-it #(apply list %)) ;; => clojure.lang.PersistentList
```

That seems to do the trick.